# Drag and Drop a div from the inside of another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I'm trying the drag and drop function of `jQuery UI` but how can I drag a `div1` inside a `div2` and drop in `div3` like this.[image: this]

My currrent code is like this

css:

```
#div2 {
     height: 52em !important;
     min-height: 50em;
     overflow:hidden;
}
```

script:

```
$( function() {
    $('#div1').draggable({
        containment: '#div4'
    });

    $('#div3').droppable();
});
```

My code doesn't seem able to drag the `div1` to `div3`

Comment: this might help Droppable - http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#photo-manager

Comment: @dekdev the `<ul>` there is not inside a `div` that separate it from the drop target div. Please see my image in the question

Comment: this is inside div - http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#default

Comment: the thing that inside that div is the `<p>` tag and isn't draggable. The draggable there is the container `<div>` it self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're wanting the actual DOM element to be moved into the new one you can do something like this (I'm not sure if there's a super fancy jQuery UI way):

```
$( function() {
    $('#div1').draggable({
        containment: '#div4'
    });

    $('#div3').droppable({ drop: function(e, opts) { 
        $(this).append(opts.draggable.detach());
    }});
});
```

Basically this will detach the `draggable` element from the DOM on the drop and append it to the `droppable` element.

You'll want to remove the positioning (relative and top/left) from the element after you drop it otherwise it will be positioned weird.