# I need to take divs that are under a div and drag and sort them to another div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm working on an application that has a div that is full of products/subproducts.  I'd like to be able to drag products from the list of products to another div.

I would like to be able to rearrange the order of products and sub products in the other div.

Here is my html:

```
<div id="product-list">
   <div class="product">Product 1</div>
   <div class="sub-product">Product 1 - Sub Product 1</div>
   <div class="sub-product">Product 1 - Sub Product 2</div>
   <div class="sub-product">Product 1 - Sub Product 3</div>
   <div class="product">Product 2</div>
   <div class="sub-product">Product 2 - Sub Product 1</div>
   <div class="sub-product">Product 2 - Sub Product 2</div>
   <div class="product">Product 3</div>
</div>

<div id="wishlist">

</div>
```

I saw this example: [Drag and Drop a div from the inside of another div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19826568/drag-and-drop-a-div-from-the-inside-of-another-div)

Unfortunately, it didn't work for me.  Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tried it out and it seems to be working fine. I can drag and drop the products and re-arrange it.

this is the js i used:

```
$( function() {
    $(".product").draggable({
    containment: "#wishlist"
    });
    $(".sub-product").draggable({
    containment: "#wishlist"
    });
    $("#wishlist").droppable({
      drop: function( event, styles ) {
        $(this)
          .addClass("style-after-drop");
      }
    });
  } );
```

Have a look at this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/khushboo097/x0c1gy2r/96/

P.S: tell me if i am missing something in your question.?

Comment: I was tired when I wrote this post, i might have been making a mistake.  Thanks for your help!